# PHP5.3 Wamp 2.2 Image functions not working

Tags: image, image-processing, wampserver, php-5.3

[image]while I am trying to build a captcha in my web application ( PHP ), its not rendering the image. So I tried with the following code, which is the simple example in php.net. But this also not rendering the image. I am using php 5.3 in wamp2.2

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: At the start of your script add error_reporting(E_ALL); and check what error you are getting..also firebug the HTTML

Comment: Hi, I tried this... no error showing in firebug .. but image is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

Enable `error reporting`.

Move your `header()` like this and let me know the case then-

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Use `Firebug` to check HTML and other bugs :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this... no error showing in firebug .. but image is not rendering

Comment: @ramesh use function_exist to check function availability first and let me know http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php